# Data access within an aspect

Tags: c#, architecture, aop, postsharp, aspect

Say I have the following layered architecture...

[image]

I want to implement an aspect that requires some form of data access. Each of the projects in the stack have reference to the aspect framework. Therefore I cannot have the aspect assembly reference the data access layer due to circular references.

So how should I go about doing data access within the aspect?

Comment: In what layer(s) do you intend to use this aspect?

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken I've actually now come up with a solution to my problem but only because the aspect is used in the service layer only, which means I can remove the references from the BLL and DAL. However I'm still interested in how it would be done if the aspect was required by all layers, being a cross cutting concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved using run-time dependencies.

Best approach for this is [*inversion of control*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) pattern.

Your data access may implement interfaces and their implementation may be retrieved during run-time by resolving who implements the whole interface using an *inversion of control* framework like [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) or [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).

Your aspects will interact with the data layer with the whole interfaces instead of design-time references, thus you'll avoid compile-time circular references.

I'd like to add some clarification: run-time dependency resolving isn't a silverbullet to produce circular reference that avoid compile-time errors.

Sometimes your implementations may be part of an assembly that once referenced in design-time may end in a circular reference, but this is just a coincidence: it may be in that assembly or in a *implementations-only* one, or just a third-party assembly. Who knows ;)

Comment: We actually already use StructureMap and a composition root assembly to handle our IoC. We also have our interfaces in separate assemblies for each layer, which means we can actually add references back from the aspect to the interface assemblies without circular references. Thanks for the lightbulb moment!

Comment: @BrettPostin No problem, hahaha ;) It's nice when someone from the other side of the Earth thinks like you, isn't it?!